# Как удалить/переместить определенное количество файлов в LINUX?

Tags: linux

В директории лежит 250 тыс. файлов.
Мне нужно скопировать 100 тыс. из них.
Условий нет, файлы практически одинаковые.

Comment: Очень здорово!)

Comment: Если нет условий, как вы сами определяете что нужно копировать, а что нет?

Comment: Берете первые 100 тыс. и копируете. Делов-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого их имена надо прочитать, подать на вход утилитке **head**, которая отсчитает нужное количество, а затем их копировать. В качестве разделителй имён файлов используется нулевой байт. Символьные ссылки также обрабатываются как есть.

```
find "$from" -type f -o -type l -print0 | head -z -n 100000 | xargs -0 cp -P -t "$to" --
```

Предложенный выше вариант работает с GNU coreutils v8.25 и GNU findutils любой вменяемой версии. Если они вам по какой-то причине не доступны, и вы не планируете копировать файлы, в именах которых есть перевод строки, можно использовать его в качестве разделителя.

```
find "$from" -type f -o -type l | head -n 100000 | xargs cp -P -t "$to" --
```

Answer (score 1):

Убрал все лишние (на мой взгляд) параметры - скрипт не сработал.
Однако порыл в интернете аналог скрипту из ответа **mymedia** и откопал единственный, который сработал у меня. Спасибо за советы.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -100000|xargs cp -t "$destdir"
```